# stringstream only works for one line then breaks when reused

Tags: c++, c++11, io, getline, stringstream

I am trying to read in a simple file (simplified below) named `trajectory.txt` that looks like this:

```
true true false
2
```

My code is simple, read in and store the the first two lines in some variables.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

int num_waypoints=0;
bool pos=1, vel=0, acc=0;
std::ifstream file;
std::string filename = "trajectory.txt";
file.open(filename.c_str());
std::string line;

// Read first 2 lines
if (std::getline(file, line)) {

  //sstream for each line
  std::stringstream ss(line);

  //first line
  std::string pos_str, vel_str, acc_str;
  ss >> pos_str >> vel_str >> acc_str;

  //evaluate
  (pos_str == "true" ? pos = true : pos = false);
  (vel_str == "true" ? vel = true : vel = false);
  (acc_str == "true" ? acc = true : acc = false);

  //second line
  if (std::getline(file, line)) {               //GDB confirms, line == "2"
    std::string num_waypoints_str;              
    ss >> num_waypoints_str;                    //THIS DOES NOTHING?
    num_waypoints = stoi(num_waypoints_str);
}

} //main()
```

The problem is that on the second to last line, `num_waypoints_str` is left empty after the stringstream is supposed to read in the values.

Using GDB I was able to confirm that the stringstream did infact take on the value of "2" but it seems to be having a problem directing the value to num_waypoints_str.

I therefore only have two questions:

1. Why would the stringstream not pass its value to the string? (Does it have to do with being within a new scope)
2. Can my code be simplified to input line 1 directly from the stringstream to the boolean `pos` or must I convert from string `pos_str` to `pos` by evaluating the string's value.

I am compiling via `g++ -g -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main`. Please try to duplicate my issue. I feel I am missing something simple.

Comment: " GDB confirms, line == "2" ", but `line != ss`. The stream `ss` contains the line that you passed to the contructor, you read the first line from it, but after that you dont change contents of `ss` but expect it to contain more lines (that you read via `getline` but not into `ss`)

Comment: If you want `ss` to contain the new line, you must give it to it: `ss.str(line)`. It won't read your mind and copy itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stringstream is not magically bound to your `std::string line;`:

```
   //second line
   if (std::getline(file, line)) {               //GDB confirms, line == "2"
     std::string num_waypoints_str;              
     ss >> num_waypoints_str;                    //THIS DOES NOTHING?
     num_waypoints = stoi(num_waypoints_str);
```

ss still has its value that was set up in the constructor much ahead of this. To be more precise:

**The [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) of std::stringstream makes a copy of the string you give it, it does not bind to it.**

You can update the content of ss by using [std::basic_stringstream::str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) if you don´t want to construct another one. **Note**: Like the other streams stringstreams have flags, like eof for example, those need to be reset too. So in your case its:

```
    ss.clear();
    ss.str(line);
```

Comment: adding in `ss.str(line)` to begin the last code block did nothing for me. I have tried calling `ss.str(std::string())` as well to clear the string stream with no results

Comment: @Max Sorry, I´ve added a clarification to my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Very close of an answer. You also need to clear the stringstream before reusing it.

```
//first use
getline(file, line);
stringstream ss(line);
ss.clear()

//second use
getline(file, line);
ss.str(line);
```